# Import data with OGR_INTERLEAVER_READING in ogr2ogr

Tags: openstreetmap, postgis

I want to import a pbf openstreetmap file to postgresql with this command :
ogr2ogr -f PostgreSQL :PG:dbname='postgis' user='postgres'" -lco OSM_MAX_TMLFILE_SIZE=10240 OGR_INTERLEAVED_READING=YES

but it import nothing.  what is OGR_INTERLEAVED_READING?
when i don't use it, it import a lot of things but stop with an error.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit cryptic, but here's how to feed in the configure options:

```
ogr2ogr -f PostgreSQL PG:"dbname='postgis' user='postgres'" test.pbf \
    --config OSM_MAX_TMLFILE_SIZE 10240 \
    --config OGR_INTERLEAVED_READING YES
```